# Can I run a power cord through a wall (not in the wall) to a plug in an unfinished space?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I am trying to add some leds to add some accent lighting to the finished part of my basement in an area where there isn’t easy power. The finished area bumps up to an unfinished area with access to the studs. In order to hide the receptacles, could I add some electric boxes in the unfinished side of the wall then run the power cord through the 1/2” drywall to power the lights on the other side? I know most power cords aren’t rated for in-wall use, but wasn’t sure about this case.

Comment: Avoid the question by plugging in and leaving the LED PSUs on the unfinished side and running the low voltage wires through the drywall to the lights.

Answer (score 2):

House-current wire running inside a wall has specific code requirements, which the cord to the power supply almost certainly does *not*.

If the LEDs themselves run on low voltage output by that power supply, you can splice the cables in that side and run them with much less concern. Even then, I would suggest considering plenum-rated wiring for the section inside the wall; that what I've done for speaker cables that will eventually be hidden, and for in-wall Ethernet wiring.

Having said that: two of the cables running through the pass-through between my home entertainment equipment and the living room are not plenum rated. Both are low voltage, though: one USB power supply in 2.1A mode, and a coax from the smart speaker's headphone jack back to the amplifier. Ideally I'd rework those with plenum cables; in practice, I haven't yet bothered.

Comment: AFAIK LV cables don't need to be plenum rated if they're not running in air ducts, even if they're running in/through walls (but they should be at least Class 2).

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Wasn't certain.